# Nearley Postprocessing is removing valid whitespaces

Tags: javascript, nearley

New to Nearley grammar, not sure what is going wrong here. Here is my grammar to get whatever is placed inside an opening and closing parenthesis.

```
@builtin "whitespace.ne"

with_in_brackets ->
    "(" _ args _ ")" {% d => ({
      type: 'inside_brackets',
      argumentstring: d[2]
    })%}
    
args -> .:* {% d => d[0].join("") %}
```

- Test Input - `(hello, "    ", world)`
- Expected Result - `{type: "inside_brackets", argumentstring: "hello, "    ", world"}`
- Actual
  Result - `{type: "inside_brackets", argumentstring: "hello, " ", world"}`

Notice - the actual result is compacting 4 whitespaces to 1 whitespace. Not sure why this is happening.

Any thoughts? FYI - I am using [Nearley Playground](https://omrelli.ug/nearley-playground/) to test my grammer on Safari v15 browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly, and we can check it by sending the result into the console.

```
with_in_brackets ->
"(" _ args _ ")" {% d => {
console.log(d[2]);
return {
  type: 'inside_brackets',
  argumentstring: d[2]
}
}%}
```

As you can see, it is just the browsers' specific behavior of turning multiple spaces into one " ", unless it is the `<pre>` tag or CSS is involved.
Also, with just whitespace between ( ) you will get multiple results because of _, so make sure to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @BaseScript. I will check as suggested. I need to dig out the code.

Comment: Sure. Let me know, if more questions will arise.